# Add data to DB2 through LotusScript

Tags: db2, lotusscript

I need to add data to a DB2 database through LotusScript from the WebQueryOpen of a webpage.  I have the agent opening the connection and I understand that I need to use an INSERT INTO command, I just am not sure of the actual syntax I need to use to accomplish the INSERT. What do I need to know?

Comment: Do you mean from Domino? Possible via connectors or odbc access according to details https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_ACCESSING_DATA_IN_ENTERPRISE_APPLICATIONS_STEPS.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to generate SQL that looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (columnName1, columname2, etc )
   VALUES ('value 1', 'value 2', etc);
```

Typically, in LotusScript, you would be doing this with something like this:

```
Dim sql as string
sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (columnName1, columname2) VALUES ('" + doc.field1(0) + "', '" + doc.field2(0) + "');"
```